# How to update a bundle from Maven artifact with running Apache Felix

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, pax-runner

Currently I have a situation, where I develop a project, then run `mvn install` and it get's put into my local Maven repository as a simple JAR file

Then, I have a crafted by some other guys "environment" which includes a whole lot of bundles and stuff, and is ultimately run via `mvn pax:run` and it takes like 5 minutes to run

I would like to be able to just run `felix:update <bundle-name>` but I cannot fill the gap between a Maven JAR artifact in local Maven repo, and a ready-for-provisioning bundle that I could put somewhere to just run `felix:update` or whatever, maybe `uninstall/install`

When I try to run `mvn pax:create-bundle` with my project, it throws a `Containing project does not have packaging type 'pom'` exception

Any help is highly appreciated

UPDATE: I've noticed that problems with re-installed bundle begin in it's activator, with a ClassNotFoundException (although the class mentioned is and always present in the bundle, so it must an issue with classpath, ClassLoader setup or whatever)

`at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation BundleWiringImpl.java:1574 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400 BundleWiringImpl.java:79 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass BundleWiringImpl.java:2018 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:357 at some.external.adapters.package.guice.SomeModule.configure SomeModule.java:46 at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure AbstractModule.java:59`

Comment: the closest I come so far is running `mvn bundle:bundle` from the project root, then in gogo console: `uninstall <bundle id>`, `install file:<path>` and `start <new bundle-id>`

However, it does not get published properly by the `portalCore`. and also I am in doubt as to why the `osgi_container/bundles/original-bundle-name` is not updated at all (might be because it contains bundles that were "download" before the container was started, so it's not that much of a problem, but still)

Comment: Attempt to start a bundle leads to an error of a kind 

`
15:35:08.375 [DEBUG] [NO_AUTH:NO_SESSION] [Gogo shell] r.o.a.f.b.activator.SomeActivator - Configure servlet support Guice module for SOME-External-Ad
apter
15:35:08.397 [ERROR] [NO_AUTH:NO_SESSION] [Gogo shell] r.o.a.f.b.activator.SomeActivator - Bundle SOME-External-Adapter. Failed to start. java.lang.No
ClassDefFoundError
  caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (some.external.adapters.package.service.callback.SomeReplyReceiver not found by SOME-External-Adapter [150
])
    at ...`

Comment: at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation BundleWiringImpl.java:1574
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400 BundleWiringImpl.java:79
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass BundleWiringImpl.java:2018
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:357
    at some.external.adapters.package.guice.SomeModule.configure SomeModule.java:46
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure AbstractModule.java:59

Comment: another attempt to re-install bundle led to 
"Address already in use" error while re-registering the bundle. so, no ClassNotFound issue. needs more investigation though

Comment: If you have important additional information, do not post it in comments where the formatting makes it impossible to process. Please edit the original question to add the information.

Comment: I did it, eventually. those comments I have kept mostly for myself. however, almost all of this turned out to be irrelevant anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a path to a file which is the newly built bundle, you can update it from the Gogo shell as follows:

```
felix:update <bundleid> file:/path/to/file
refresh
```

Where `<bundleid>` is the numeric ID of the bundle that you want to update. The `refresh` command is needed in case any bundles depend on or import packages from the bundle you are updating; this command will cause the Framework to attempt to re-resolve them using the new dependency.

Comment: thanks, I was going to post my own answer but will look into your recipe, it's one line less

Comment: Good to hear you've solved the problem. If you tell me what you had to do, I might be able to identify what was really going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to accept @neil-bartlett's answer, though I have to add some more context:

1) one of the biggest issues I had initially is that a JAR-file in local Maven repo IS NOT THE SAME as an OSGi bundle. In order to create bundle, I had to run `mvn bundle:bundle` AFTER `mvn install`. And the bundle got created in `target/` folder.

2) afterwards, in a GoGo shell, I could indeed run `felix:update <bundle-id> file:C:/Users/blablabla/bundle-SNAPSHOT-2.0.jar`, and for some reasons, these days it *just works*. The exceptions, mentioned in updates to original post, are indeed occurring, but they do not prevent proper installation of an updated bundle.